# Flutter error: The argument type 'NumberTrivia' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'NumberTriviaModel'

Tags: flutter, dart

I following a YouTube Flutter app series Where I cant figure out the error while in the video I cant see any error, but in my IDE there's showing an error:

**1.** number_trivia.dart

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class NumberTrivia extends Equatable {
  final String text;
  final int number;

  NumberTrivia({
    required this.text,
    required this.number,
  }) : super();
}
```

**2.** number_trivia_model.dart

```
import '../../domain/entities/number_trivia.dart';

class NumberTriviaModel extends NumberTrivia {
  NumberTriviaModel({
    required String text,
    required int number,
  }) : super(text: text, number: number);

  factory NumberTriviaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NumberTriviaModel(
      text: json["text"],
      number: (json["number"] as num).toInt(),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "text": text,
        "number": number,
      };
}
```

**3.** number_trivia_repository_impl.dart      // *The error file*

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

import '../../../../core/error/exception.dart';
import '../../../../core/error/failures.dart';
import '../../../../core/platform/network_info.dart';
import '../../domain/entities/number_trivia.dart';
import '../../domain/repositories/number_trivia_repository.dart';
import '../datasources/number_trivia_local_data_source.dart';
import '../datasources/number_trivia_remote_data_source.dart';

typedef Future<NumberTrivia> _ConcreteOrRandomChooser();

class NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl implements NumberTriviaRepository {
  final NumberTriviaRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;
  final NumberTriviaLocalDataSource localDataSource;
  final NetworkInfo networkInfo;

  NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl(
    @required this.remoteDataSource,
    @required this.localDataSource,
    @required this.networkInfo,
  );

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>> getConcreteNumberTrivia(
    int number,
  ) async {
    return await _getTrivia(() {
      return remoteDataSource.getConreteNumberTrivia(number);
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>> getRandomNumberTrivia() async {
    return await _getTrivia(() {
      return remoteDataSource.getRandomNumberTrivia();
    });
  }

  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>> _getTrivia(
    _ConcreteOrRandomChooser getConcreteOrRandom,
  ) async {
    if (await networkInfo.isConnected) {
      try {
        final remoteTrivia = await getConcreteOrRandom();
        localDataSource.cacheNumberTrivia(remoteTrivia);     // The error
        return Right(remoteTrivia);
      } on ServerException {
        return Left(ServerFailure());
      }
    } else {
      try {
        final localTrivia = await localDataSource.getLastNumberTrivia();
        return Right(localTrivia);
      } on CacheException {
        return Left(CacheFailure());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `remoteTrivia` variable was declared before as `final` but still, it's showing the error on that word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localDataSource.cacheNumberTrivia(remoteTrivia);
```

to this :

```
localDataSource.cacheNumberTrivia(remoteTrivia as NumberTriviaModel);
```